# Add review button in each post to review it as Low Quality Post

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

Sometimes, when I open any question, I found some answers which are *link only* or *commentary to other posts*. So I comment manually which is used in *Low Quality Post Review*. But I can not *Recommend Deletion*. So I suggest to add *review* button in each post(for 2K+ users only) (something like *close* button in question for 3K+ users.)

[image]

It should be also in other reviews pages. (i.e. *Review First Posts* like this:)

[image]

I think we should not flag any link only answer as *not an answer*.

Does adding *review* button in the post make sense?

Comment: Green freehand arrows and black not-so-freehand lines? I'm not sure I can take this seriously... :p

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly should happen some when 'review' button is pressed?

Comment: @Flow - What happen when we click on `Recommend Deletion`?

Comment: Ahh, then this is (nearly) a duplicate of [my feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195606/). But I have to say, I had a hard time figuring out what excalty your suggestion is.

Comment: @Flow - The only difference I can say is: Your question is for 10K+ users and moderators while I am talking about everyone.

Comment: Yes, and for the same reason I don't suggest adding a new "review" button but altering the delete button behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> I found some answers which are link only or commentary to other posts.

Both of these are grounds for flagging something as "Not an answer", in my opinion.  The only unfortunate side effect is that this puts more load on moderators rather than bringing the answer to the attention of 20K users able to cast delete votes on answers (as is done with the Review queue).

Comment: Can you tell me how review(low quality) works? Suppose, 5 reviewer Recommend deletion. Then will that post get deleted or will it go to moderator's attention?

Comment: @hims056 I'm not absolutely sure, that's a mystery to me, too.  I have looked back at the "History" and seen many more than 5 recommend deletes I think, but that's just anecdotal.