# Can I manually nominate Low Quality Posts?

Tags: feature-request, support, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add review button in each post to review it as Low Quality Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147073/add-review-button-in-each-post-to-review-it-as-low-quality-post)

Is there a way to manually recommend deletion or nominate posts for the Low Quality Posts review queue while browsing questions?

Currently I downvote and flag as "Not an answer", but as I understand it these flags create (unnecessary) load for moderators, when the issues could generally be handled by the review process instead. Also, I'm not sure it is appropriate to flag "link only" answers as "Not an answer".

Another problem with this approach is that I can't add one of the template comments from the LQP review screen. If I'm not feeling *too* lazy I'll type a comment of my own, but I feel the template ones are worded better and would rather use one of those.

Also, if a post is *already* on the LQP queue, it would be nice if I could review it directly from the question page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147073/187824