# Also show "Add a comment for the author" selection when deleting/voting to delete an answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

I'm aware that this only affects high rep users and mods, but nevertheless it would be nice if the following selection would appear when a user casts a delete vote on an answer.

[image: Add a comment for the author selection]

If I am not mistaken, this only appears when casting delete votes from the review queues. I don't see a reason why this shouldn't also appear when casting a vote directly to the answer, instead of the (java script) alert with "Delete this post?".

Or in other words, the selection should always appear when a user does some kind of 'delete answer' action.

Comment: Related: [Add review button in each post to review it as Low Quality Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147073/187824)

Comment: Use [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) in the interim?

Comment: Note that the [other feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147073/add-review-button-in-each-post-to-review-it-as-low-quality-post) suggest a slightly different approach.