# Show me if a post is in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

Every day we walk by posts that are in the review queue and we don't even know it.

#### Why can't we add a new review link to see that?

Example:

[image: post to review]

I think people would be interested, click it and maybe review it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add review button in each post to review it as Low Quality Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147073/add-review-button-in-each-post-to-review-it-as-low-quality-post)

Comment: @hims056 That feature request is unclear to me, but I don't think this is a duplicate of it

Comment: Since, in the normal post view, you can take any action on the post that you could in review, what's the purpose of this? The review queue is just for bringing attention to possible problems. If you're already at the problem, you don't need the queue.

Comment: @him Probably not a duplicate. That one is only about low quality posts. This one is more general (+1)

Comment: Are you suggesting that if the post is in any review it should show it?

Comment: @hims056: Exactly.

Comment: If it is in suggested edit it already show us. (as "edit(1)"), If it needs close vote or reopen vote we can see that too. First votes/ Late answer's actions can be taken without opening a review page/popup. What remain is action for less than 10K users to recommend deletion which can't be done directly on the post. That's what I am suggesting there.

Comment: I'm with @Josh on this. juergen can you expand on the added value such thing will add in your opinion, maybe I missed something?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It could be an indicator that there is something wrong with the post. Maybe I did not see it but someone else. If I click on the review link I can verify and review it.

Comment: @juergend still, like Josh said you will see everything already: downvotes, comments, existing close votes. What action done in the review to can't be seen on the post itself?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd may be for low quality, but before the close queue close(1). so for the user can understand about his low quality post and escape from close review queue.

Comment: @Bala so in such case it was already [suggested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147073/add-review-button-in-each-post-to-review-it-as-low-quality-post).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not suggested for 2K, but for actual questioner.

Comment: I think it's not needed. If you don't see a reason to vote / flag on the post page, why should you do it if it is in review? Only "recommend deletion" is not available, and with a suggestion strictly about it I might possibly agree.

Comment: @sha But now you can't find the review entry from the post. With a link you can see at what state of the review process is, and what each reviewer decided.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd A <20k rep user can reccomend deletion of a VLQ post in the review queue, and have access to canned comments (that notify the user even if the post is deleted), neither of which are available from the post itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think this feature will be particularly useful for the cases when you vote/flag to close/reopen a question.

A link to the review entry would allow the voter/flagger to monitor the review process and see if the review is complete, or if there are more votes to come.